# Explain the JS function

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand the solution mentioned in [the page](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-function-exercise-19.php)  but I'm not getting the heads or tails, can someone please `ELI5` for `JS?`

```js
function BiggerElements(val)
   {
     return function(evalue, index, array)
     {
     return (evalue >= val);
     };
   }
var result = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10]. filter(BiggerElements(10));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will just filter the results which are greater than `val` i-e 10 in your case.

Comment: I was about to edit your awful code formatting, but wow that's copy/pasted from the original source. Epic fail w3c. I hate to judge a book by it's cover, but you *may* want to find a different resource to use for learning JS. As for your question, it's a function that takes a value and returns a function that you can pass to `Array.prototype.filter` and get an array of elements >= the original value. This is a case of [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: I agree with @JaredSmith, formatting is awful and you shouldn't start a function's name with capital unless it is a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

For your better understanding, I have simplified the code as below.

```
var result = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10].filter(items=> items >= 10);
console.log(result);
```

Her the `filter` function will filter out all the elements greater than or equal to 10.

So the result will be

```
[11,45,31,64,10]
```

You find out the detailed documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to ELY5:

You have an array with values:

```
 [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10]
```

Someone wants to only see the values that are at least 10, which would be:

```
 [11, 45, 31, 64, 10]
```

In order to do that for *any* array of values, you would naively do something like this:

```
let array = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10];
let result = []; // We will collect the wanted values in here
for (let value of array) { // Read each value from the array
    if (value >= 10) { // Does it meet the requirement?
        result.push(value);  // Yes, let's collect that value
    }
}
console.log(result); // [11, 45, 31, 64, 10]
```

Now, there is an Array method that can make this filter-job a bit more concise: `filter`. You need to pass it a function, which will be executed for each value in the array. When that function returns a truthy value (like `true`) then it will be collected, otherwise not. The collected result array will be returned by `filter`:

```
let array = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10];
let result = array.filter(function (value) {
    return value >= 10; // this is false or true
});
console.log(result); // [11, 45, 31, 64, 10]
```

Note that we do not `push` anymore. `filter` does that job for us.

Now we could have written that inner function as an arrow function, but let's not diverge... We could define that inner function with a proper name:

```
function atLeast10(value) {
    return value >= 10; // this is false or true
}
```

...and then we can just reference that function, to get exactly the same:

```
let array = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10];
let result = array.filter(atLeast10);
console.log(result); // [11, 45, 31, 64, 10]
```

Now someone says: *"OK that's all very nice, but if next time I want only values that are at least 11, then I cannot use `atLeast10`. I cannot see myself creating a function for each different limit I want to work with: `atLeast10`, `atLeast11`, `atLeast12`, ...etc."*

And now we come to the smart part. We could make a *function* to solve that "problem". This function will have to return to me a tailor-made function like `atLeast10`, but then of course based on a value I will give it:

```
function createMyAtLeastFunction(threshold) {
    // We define here our tailor made function:
    function atLeast(value) {
        return value >= threshold; // we can reference threshold!
    }
    return atLeast; // ...and we can return this tailor made function
}
```

Notice that:

If we call `createMyAtLeastFunction`, the inner function is not (yet) called. It is just returned. But if ever that returned function gets called, it has access to `threshold`. This is called a *closure*.

We don't even have to use a separate `return atLeast`... we can immediately return the function expression:

```
function createMyAtLeastFunction(threshold) {
    return function (value) { // No need to name it... just return it
        return value >= threshold;
    }
}
```

So now we can easily change our mind and use 10, 11, or any other threshold value, by first getting our tailor-made function:

```
let atLeast10 = createMyAtLeastFunction(10);
// atLeast10 is a function! It will return true when I call it 
// with a value that is at least 10:
let array = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10];
let result = array.filter(atLeast10);
console.log(result); // [11, 45, 31, 64, 10]
```

I can even create it on-the-fly:

```
let array = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10];
let result = array.filter(createMyAtLeastFunction(10));
console.log(result); // [11, 45, 31, 64, 10]
```

If I want to filter for values that are at least 11, I only have to change it in this main program:

```
let array = [11, 45, 4, 31, 64, 10];
let result = array.filter(createMyAtLeastFunction(11));
console.log(result); // [11, 45, 31, 64]
```

Some comments about the original code:

`BiggerElements` is not such a good name, because:

- it starts with a capital, which most would like to reserve for constructors/classes
- it generates a function which also allows for *equal* values, so not always "bigger".

Also the name `evalue` does not really ring a bell to me. I have chosen the name `threshold`.

It is maybe also confusing that in the original code the returned function takes 3 arguments. This is not wrong, as indeed `filter` will pass three arguments, but since in our case those 2 other arguments are not used, they don't need to be specified.

The extra parentheses around the `>=` expression are not needed (they don't hurt either).

Hope this clarifies it.